# Test-Path -isValid fails on UNC root share

Tags: powershell, unc

I need to be able to test the validity of a path, regardless of actual presence. My function is used to validate a user provided path, which might be a local drive and might be a UNC path and might be a registry path. And the path could then be used as the location to create a new folder, delete the path, as the source or destination of a copy, etc.
`Test-Path $path -isValid` works, with one exception, when the path is the root of a UNC share.
So when `$path = '\\Server\Folder'` I get true, but when `$path = '\\Server'` I get false, even though `\\Server` is a perfectly valid path.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394904/powershell-test-path-returns-false-when-testing-a-network-share) which suggests using `([System.Uri]$path).IsUnc` but that returns true when `$path = '\\Px\Folder\|'` which is in fact a totally invalid path.
I can probably expand my logic to test if a path is in fact a share root, then handle things differently, but I wonder if I am missing some built in solution that actually works across all situations as I expected `Test-Path -isValid` to do. The fact that this is still broken in the PS 5.1 I am testing on is a bit disappointing. Or am I missing something and no rational person who'll want to test `\\Server` as a valid path because no one would copy a file to such a path, or create a folder there? That is of course a rhetorical equation and sarcasm, I had had MANY times when I needed to do exactly that, thus the attempt to automate such things.

On a slight tangent, is there an accepted RegEx for validating a UNC path, that handles invalid characters appropriately? If I had a set of RegEx expressions so I could ID a local path, UNC path or a Registry path, then validate each for disallowed characters, that could work.

EDIT: I am an idiot. `$path = '\\Server'` is NOT a valid path, you need both a server AND a share to define a valid path. That'll teach me to do RegEx stuff while tired.

Comment: As an aside, I think this should cover you for a [UNC path regex](https://regex101.com/r/1B8Cxd/2).

Comment: @ash, I wonder if you could help me understand why the first \ is outside the non capturing group, while the second one is part of the non capturing group?

Comment: Aha, I think I see it. It's there to catch not only the first instance of \someothercharacters but also any further folders in the path.

Comment: Consider adding your findings as an answer to you question instead of an Edit, so that you can mark it solved.