# Powershell UNC Path Test-Path

Tags: powershell, unc

How do I test-path using UNC rather than mapped letter drive

This returns True

```
Test-Path -Path Y:\FNDDEV
```

Windows explorer

```
PC > EAMDEV(\\Eamcifsdev.lirrad.lirr.org) (Y:) > FNDDEV
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell Test-Path returns False when testing a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394904/powershell-test-path-returns-false-when-testing-a-network-share)

Comment: This returns false   Test-Path -Path '\\EAMDEV\Y$\FNDDEV'

Comment: What happens when you use `-LiteralPath` ? Check the `Y:` mapping. Is this really pointing to `\\EAMDEV\Y$` ?

Comment: What does `Net Use` show for Y?

Comment: This works.  Can someone explain why?

Comment: test-path -path 'Filesystem::\\Eamcifsdev.lirrad.lirr.org\EAMDEV\FNDDEV'

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the UNC path of a network drive just use `Get-PSDrive`. It will gather all of the information about a drive including the provider, root, current location, used space, free space, and name.

```
$drive = Get-PSDrive -Name (get-location).Drive.Name
```

For instance the `name` parameter is used as the current drive letter by using `Get-Location`.

```
$root = if($drive.DisplayRoot -ne $null){$drive.DisplayRoot} else {$drive.Root}
```

We compare the `.Root` data with the drive letter and network location. `.DisplayRoot` gives us the network location / network path. `.Root` gives us the drive letter. It will be `Null` if it is a local path as there is no `.DisplayRoot` to provide.

```
Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath $drive.CurrentLocation
```

Lastly using `Join-Path` put it all together to give the network path and current location if it is a mapped drive. If not you will get just the drive letter.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with UNC formatted as follows:

\Eamcifsdev.lirrad.lirr.org\EAMDEV\FNDDEV\docuploads\MTADEV4\Backup

thanks for responding